# Scroll function doesn´t work in mobile browser fullscreen mode?

Tags: javascript, mobile, fullscreen, android-fullscreen

I have requesting fullscreen mode through javascript fullscreen API with this library Screenfull.js. This is working pretty good in my webapp on mobile devices with mobile chrome. But why is not working scroll function at all?

Is this just truly bug of browser? If yes have you tried somebody figure it somehow ?

I have tried make function separately with [iscroll](https://github.com/cubiq/iscroll) but on mobile devices is really slow and not smooth at all.

Thanks for any advice

Answer (score 0):

did you tried with chrome emulator or with a phone? sometimes chrome just go crazy! 
close al task and restart!

and why do you need to use screenfull for your mobile app? :/

well i tried with emulator, and when the browser use the fullscreen the scroll doesnt work. I think that library is not good idea for mobile...